# Why do films from before 1917 seem to run faster than normal?

Tags: cinema-history

Why do the scenes in the films of year 1917 and before seem to run faster than the normal speed? Does it have to do something with the equipment of that era or that the actors used to act like that?

Comment: Please invest more care when asking your question. The tag you used was irrelevant, the title is meaningless, and in fact the question was answered years ago.

Comment: @BCdotWEB While noble aspirations indeed, two of those can be fixed and one doesn't seem the asker's fault.